# Access to ambiguous class member

Tags: c++

Ive got a diamond. I want to access class member. I am using mingw.
**Question is**: **How to access member "top::A"** without redeclaring classes

```
#include <cstdio>
class top {
public:
    const char A;
    top(): A('t') {}
};
class left: public top {
public:
    const char A;
    left():A('l'){}
};
class right: public top {};
class bottom: public left, public right {};

int main() {
    bottom obj;
    printf("%c\n", obj.bottom::right::A); //using right::A, inherited from top::A
    printf("%c\n", obj.bottom::left::A); //using left::A and left::top::A is hidden
    //printf("%c\n", obj.bottom::left::top::A); //error. How to access it?
    return 0;
}
```

When I remove comment mingw gives me an error:

```
'top' is an ambiguous base of 'bottom'
```

Update: Looks like casting types works:

```
printf("%c\n", static_cast<top>(static_cast<left>(obj)).A);
printf("%c\n", static_cast<left>(obj).::top::A);
printf("%c\n", reinterpret_cast<top&>(obj).A);//considered bad
printf("%c\n", (reinterpret_cast<top*>(&obj))->A);//considered evil
//      printf("%c\n", static_cast<top&>(obj).A);//error
```

Comment: See The Annotated C++ Reference Manual, section 10.11c.  Also, don't have diamonds in your inheritance.  It's bad.

Comment: Do you want to know about virtual inheritance, or do you actually want to know how to access the two separate, non-virtual copies of `top`?

Comment: @Kerrek actually want how to access two separate non-virtual copies of top, because memory contains it.

Comment: @all: see my answer - you can cast your variables to a specific base class to aid the resolution.

Comment: Don't use `reinterpret_cast` -- that's cheating the compiler, who is your friend. Use `static_cast` instead, since derived types are convertible to base types. Also you don't need pointers, you can perfectly well cast references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without going for virtual inheritance, you can massage the type a bit to convince the compiler to pick the correct base class:

```
printf("%c\n", static_cast<left&>(obj).::top::A);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite a C++ guru, but mightn't the following work?

```
left &asLeft = obj ;
top &asTop = asLeft ;
cout << asTop.A << endl ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Dimond problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Comment: I saw it. But object contains obj.bottom::left::top::A in memory